# "X was the year I ..." vs "In X, I ..."

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Example:

> 1999 was the year I devoted myself fully to marine biology.
>
> In 1999, I devoted myself fully to marine biology.

Is there any difference between the two sentences? Do they have a different focus? Or they mean basically the same thing?

Comment: The first puts great focus and emphasis on the specific year. We might expect it to be followed by something like "It was also the year I met Jane: the year that changed everything". The second sentence, by contrast, is more about your decision to study marine biology, and calls less attention to itself generally. More of a factual statement. I don't think the term applies in this case, but emphasizing by employing unusual or atypical word order is known as *hyperbation*.

Comment: The main difference is that the first indicates that 1999 was *the* year, while the second indicates that 1999 was *a* year -- ie, a single year vs one of possibly several.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first version has an implicit "**in which**" in it, as in "1999 was the year in which I devoted myself ...". So the grammar is pretty similar, it is a matter of emphasis.